# How can I prevent a window switcher from popping up when I drag a window to the edge of my display?

Tags: gnome, snap-windows

I like to snap my windows in GNOME to one side of the display or the other and to snap them into one of the corners of the display. I can do this by dragging the window using the mouse or by pressing the Super key with a direction key.

I had done this for years. But recently, every time I drag any window to the edge of my display and let it snap into position, I immediately then get a window switcher popup, basically the same popup I'd see if I were switching windows by pressing the Alt and Tab keys.

How can I stop this popup from appearing after I snap a window?

In case it helps, I use [Tiling Assistant](https://github.com/Leleat/Tiling-Assistant) together with [Just Perfection](https://gitlab.gnome.org/jrahmatzadeh/just-perfection) (the latter is used to put the panel with the clock to the bottom of the display).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window switcher popup appears to be opened by the *"Gnome extension Tiling Assistant"* which you have installed ... So, either disable/remove [Tiling Assistant](https://github.com/Leleat/Tiling-Assistant) altogether or go to its options and disable *Tiling Popup*-->*Open after tiling a window*:

[image]

Comment: You found it! Magic, thanks very much for your guidance on that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Should you get to this question after the update to ubuntu 23.10. In 'Settings' under 'Ubuntu Desktop' there is a 'Enhanced Tiling' option that can be switched off:
[image]